# Run jQuery toggle in three parts

Tags: jquery

I want below jquery code to run in 3 parts.

1. Part-1, run once only on page load
2. Part-2, run on 1st click only
3. Part-3, run on 2nd and any furthur clicking

but it is not running according to my need.

```
    $('.myClass').toggle(function() {
        alert('Part-1, run once only on page load');
    }, function() {
        alert('Part-2, run on 1st click only');
    }, function() {
        alert('Part-3, run on 2nd and any furthur clicking');
    }).click();
```

Comment: split it to 3 callbacks, that's not how you use `toggle`

Comment: @HagaiWild how to do that, I am not good in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will be to split those callbacks to 2 events,
The first event is 'ready' event, in this case:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    alert('Part-1, run onece only on page load');
});
```

After that you need to create another event binding:

```
$('.myClass').one('click', function() { 
    alert('Part-2, run on 1st click only');

   $(this).click(function() { 
      alert('Part-3, run on 2nd and any furthur clicking');
   });
});
```

The seconds event happens only on the first click, that's when your binding for all later clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really get what you're trying to finally achieve, but here is the code that does exactly what you described:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.myClass').toggle();
    alert('Part-1, runs once only on page load');

    var isMyClassEverClicked = false;
    $('.myClass').click(function() {
        if (!isMyClassEverClicked) {
            $('.myClass').toggle();
            alert('Part-2, run on 1st click only');
            isMyClassEverClicked = true;
            return;
        }

        $('.myClass').toggle();
        alert('Part-3, run on 2nd and any furthur clicking');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Anything what should run once can be run in [document ready functionn here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
2. How many times it was clicked can be simply counted in local variable and used in the logic. [JQuery click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mybrave/7e9tyh1L/1/)

```
var clickCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Part-1, run once only on page load');
})

$('.myClass').click(function() {
    if (clickCount == 0){
        alert('Part-2, run on 1st click only');
    }
    if (clickCount >= 1){
        alert('Part-3, run on 2nd and any furthur clicking');
    }

    clickCount++;
});
```